# How should I correctly format a variable in an include?

Tags: php, include

I am currently working on a new project and I am looking to grab a 'description' from a text file and display it. This is my code so far, but I have done something wrong on line 11 (with the include), I am sure its a pretty **noobie problem**, but if someone could fix it that would be brilliant.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';

foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $resdir) {
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    echo "
<div class=\"span3\">
<div class=\"tile\">
<img src=\"resources/" . $resdir . "/thumbnail.png\" class=\"img-rounded\">
<h3 class=\"tile-title\">" . $resdir . "</h3>
<p>" include('resources/'.$_GET['resdir'].'description.txt'); "</p>
<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block\" href=\"http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/"  . $resdir . "/\">More Information</a>
</div>
</div>
" 
;
}
```

( [copy on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/X5z5dMLw) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the two line with this one.

```
<h3 class=\"tile-title\">" . $resdir . "</h3>
<p>"; echo  include('resources/'.$_GET['Mydir'].'description.txt'); echo "</p>
```

Comment: Thanks You 'php NoOb' 
I replaced the two lines with the one you provided, and although I no longer get a 500 error, then description.txt file is still not showing up. Here is the site if that helps at all: http://www.baboonhut.com/

Comment: @JamesRainsford Ok, but what is `$_GET['Mydir']` What does it echo out

Comment: Ah sorry I accidental pasted a slightly older version of the code, that is now and should have been $_GET['resdir'], and resdir gets the name of the sub folders in the folder 'resources'

Comment: But, still I asked you what does it echo out? I need to see the path that takes to the resources.txt file

Comment: At the moment the code isnt 'echo'ing out anything at all, the path should be "resources/(the name of the project)/description.txt

Comment: Well, it is not including the file, because maybe the name of the project does not exist. You can manually write something in-between resources - and - description.txt and run your code, you should it it is works or not

Comment: I got it working, not sure where the "$_GET['resdir']" came from, but I replaced that with ". $resdir ." and it is working well now, looks like I just need to two 'echo's. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @JamesRainsford No problem, glad it worked for you. You can check my room on **[Ajax](chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30213/ajax)** . if you have more question, just leave it there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to concatenate, which you can't do with an include. basically you would would to make them 3 different statements like this:

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';

foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $resdir) {
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    echo "<div class=\"span3\">
    <div class=\"tile\">
    <img src=\"resources/" . $resdir . "/thumbnail.png\" class=\"img-rounded\">
    <h3 class=\"tile-title\">" . $resdir . "</h3>
    <p>";

    include('resources/'.$_GET['Mydir'].'description.txt'); 

    echo "</p>
    <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block\" href=\"http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/"  . $resdir . "/\">More Information</a>
    </div>
    </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another option is to read a file

```
$file = fopen('resources/'.$_GET['Mydir'].'description.txt', "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br>";
  }
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use two separate `echo` statements or the `?> ... <?php` syntax:

```
    ?>
<div class="span3">
<div class="tile">
<img src="resources/<?php echo $resdir; ?>/thumbnail.png" class="img-rounded">
<h3 class="tile-title"><?php echo $resdir; ?></h3>
<p><?php include('resources/'.$_GET['Mydir'].'description.txt'); ?></p>
[...]
    <?php
```

I will note that the above code could allow anybody to [read any file](/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability) the web server has access to, by including `..` in the value of `$_GET['Mydir']` (and the null byte, escaped as `%00`, to read even files that do not end in `.txt`).

Also, if the text file includes user input, this could allow the attacker to execute arbitrary PHP code on the server (*e.g.* to use it for sending spam). Better is to do something like this:

```
<?php

    $mydir = $_GET['Mydir'];
    if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $mydir)) {
        die('Invalid directory name; must consist of only letters and digits');
    }
    $contents = file_get_contents("resources/$mydir/description.txt");
    if ($contents === false) {
        die('Failed to read file');
    }
    echo htmlspecialchars($contents);

?>
```